# How do I mark a message as read?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, pyrogram

How do I mark a message as read?

```
app = Client(session_name, api_id, api_hash)


@app.on_message()
async def my_handler(client, message):
    await app.send_message(message.from_user.username, "ok boss")
    await app.read_chat_history(message.from_user.username)

app.run()
```

[image]

I expected the bot's message to be ticked that he had read it

Comment: Please don't use unrelated tags just because they have "python" and "telegram" in the name. Tags have descriptions for a reason.

Comment: You want the 'read' check's to be seen by a message send by a bot?

Comment: yes, otherwise the bot does not look like a human :-(

Answer (score 0):

## [Client.read_chat_history()](https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/methods/read_chat_history#read-chat-history)

Mark a chat’s message history as read.

**Usable by**

- [X] Users
- [ ] Bots

Parameters:

- **chat_id**  (`int`  |  `str`) – Unique identifier (int) or username (str) of the target chat. For your personal cloud (Saved Messages) you can simply use “me” or “self”. For a contact that exists in your Telegram address book you can use his phone number (str).
- **max_id**  (`int`,  *optional*) – The id of the last message you want to mark as read; all the messages before this one will be marked as read as well. Defaults to 0 (mark every unread message as read).

Returns:

`bool`  - On success, True is returned.

EXAMPLE

```py
# Mark the whole chat as read
await app.read_chat_history(chat_id)

# Mark messages as read only up to the given message id
await app.read_chat_history(chat_id, 12345)
```

Comment: I have tried this method does not work

Comment: This is not the Bot api, rather the User api to make your own client where you can use this method to set the history has read, it does not answer OP's question at all

Answer (score 0):

> I expected the bot's message to be ticked that he had read it

This is not possible, messages send by a Telegram Bot will never get those checkmarks.

Those marks are only for messages send from a user-account